# SSRS SSDT I am trying to display a 2nd field (from the same dataset) in a matrix, in the same column

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

Interesting problem I've been stuck on because it seems so simple.

I am using Visual Studio 2010

```
=Fields!AccountName.Value & Fields!LeaveName.Value
```

Looking to pull in the `LeaveName`

My example should display `Leave without Pay: Salary Savings`

The field Leave without Pay is from (AccountName.Value) if there is data from there I would like the expression to add a colon (:) if there is a 2nd value coming, 2nd value Salary Savings is from (LeaveName.Value)

prior to posting my question I had tried

**=Fields!AccountName.Value + IIF(IsNothing(Fields!LeaveName.Value),": ", "")**

which gave no error an also did not pull in the data. I have a test example where I know the person has used Leave without pay: Salary Savings

FIX. added below expression to text box properties

```
=Fields!AccountName.Value + iif(IsNothing(Fields!LeaveName.Value),"",": "+Fields!LeaveName.Value)
```

additionally needed to play with Row Groups then went to Tablix properties
1. Filter Tablix. 
 a. expression `=Fields!AccountName.Value + Fields!LeaveName.Value`
 b. `<> Leave with Pay`
 c. expression `=Fields!AccountName.Value + Fields!LeaveName.Value`
 d. `<> Leave without Pay`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's simply:

```
=Fields!AccountName.Value + iif(IsNothing(Fields!LeaveName.Value),"",": "+Fields!LeaveName.Value)
```

or if that doesn't match anything, maybe this:

```
=Fields!AccountName.Value + iif(Trim(Cstr(Fields!LeaveName.Value))="","",": "+Fields!LeaveName.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was certain it would be utilizing IFF(IsNothing but... I'm sure your code is correct, but I doesn't seem to pull in the data on my test example. prior to posting my question I had tried =Fields!AccountName.Value + IIF(IsNothing(Fields!LeaveName.Value),": ", "") which gave no error an also did not pull in the data.

Comment: Try my edited 2nd suggestion.  It helps to know what is in your database.. whether it's NULLs or blank strings.

Comment: it was NULLs... your code was correct. i needed to filter out the nulls for it to work. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate string values using '+'

What you would be looking for is something like:

```
=Fields!AccountName.Value + ": " + Fields!LeaveName.Value
```

Comment: verified this is the correct code just needed a filter see main post